# Error using PIL in a virtualenv in IBM Cloud Functions: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to define an IBM Cloud Function in Python using PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
...
```

I use Pycharm to do my development. In Pycharm, under `site-packages` in my Python runtime, I see `PIL` and `Pillow-4.3.0:dist-info`. When I run my code locally from within Pycharm it works fine.

I built a `virtualenv` with the same Python runtime and my code in order to include dependencies not part of the Cloud Functions Python runtime. Examining the `virtualenv`, I can see the same libraries:

```
\virtualenv
  \bin
  \include
  \lib
    \python3.6 
      \site-packages
        ...
        \PIL
        \Pillow-4.3.0:dist-info
        ...
```

However, when I execute my code as a Cloud Function with this `virtualenv` runtime, I see an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`.

I'm thinking the error is with how I've constructed my `virtualenv`, but I'm at a loss as it looks like the same libraries are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out the immediate problem. It was a simple error in my deploy script. While my `virtualenv` content looked fine locally, I had a deployment error that resulted in something other than what I'd intended getting deployed. Now, next error: `ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'`